# As of react-scripts >=2 you must specify targeted browsers - the browserlist is already in the package.json

Tags: node.js, reactjs, bitbucket-pipelines

When I run the yarn build script in my pipeline for our react app, it runs

```
node --max-old-space-size=8192 scripts/build.js
```

Then I get the following error

Failed to compile.

```
As of react-scripts >=2 you must specify targeted browsers.
Please add a browserslist key to your package.json.
```

However, the browserlist is already in the package.json

```json
{
  "name":"nova-web",
  "version":"21.0.0",
  "license":"UNLICENSED",
  "private":true,
  "dependencies":{
    "@babel/core":"7.8.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript":"^7.12.1",
    "@emotion/react":"^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled":"^11.10.5",
    "@loadable/component":"^5.12.0",
    "@mui/icons-material":"^5.11.0",
    "@mui/material":"^5.11.0",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc":"^5.11.0",
    "@mui/x-data-grid":"^5.17.19",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit":"^1.8.2",
    "@sentry/react":"^5.19.2",
    "@svgr/webpack":"4.3.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom":"5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react":"12.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event":"13.2.1",
    "@types/classnames":"^2.2.10",
    "@types/crypto-js":"^3.1.44",
    "@types/jest":"^27.0.2",
    "@types/js-cookie":"^2.2.6",
    "@types/loadable__component":"^5.10.0",
    "@types/lodash":"^4.14.149",
    "@types/node":"^12.0.0",
    "@types/pluralize":"^0.0.29",
    "@types/react":"^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom":"^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-helmet":"^6.1.0",
    "@types/react-html-parser":"^2.0.1",
    "@types/react-redux":"^7.1.7",
    "@types/react-router":"^5.1.4",
    "@types/react-router-dom":"^5.1.3",
    "@types/react-sticky":"^6.0.3",
    "@types/react-timeago":"^4.1.1",
    "@types/recharts":"^1.8.14",
    "@types/smoothscroll-polyfill":"^0.3.1",
    "@types/styled-components":"^5.1.26",
    "accesscontrol":"^2.2.1",
    "antd":"^4.7.2",
    "array-move":"^3.0.1",
    "axios":"^0.19.2",
    "babel-eslint":"10.0.3",
    "babel-jest":"27.2.1",
    "babel-loader":"8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-import":"^1.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import":"^0.3.6",
    "babel-preset-react-app":"^9.1.1",
    "camelcase":"^5.3.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin":"2.3.0",
    "chai":"^4.3.4",
    "change-case":"^4.1.1",
    "classnames":"^2.2.6",
    "crypto-js":"^4.0.0",
    "css-loader":"^3.4.2",
    "cypress":"^9.0.0",
    "date-fns":"^2.13.0",
    "dnd-core":"^10.0.2",
    "dotenv":"8.2.0",
    "dotenv-expand":"5.1.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app":"^5.2.0",
    "eslint-loader":"3.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype":"4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import":"^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y":"6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks":"^1.6.1",
    "file-loader":"4.3.0",
    "fs-extra":"^8.1.0",
    "graphql-request":"^1.8.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin":"4.0.0-beta.11",
    "identity-obj-proxy":"^3.0.0",
    "immutability-helper":"^3.0.2",
    "immutable":"^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "jest":"27.2.1",
    "jest-watch-typeahead":"0.4.2",
    "js-cookie":"^2.2.1",
    "json-to-graphql-query":"^2.0.0",
    "lodash":"^4.17.15",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin":"^0.10.0",
    "mixpanel-browser":"^2.40.0",
    "moment-timezone":"^0.5.33",
    "node-sass":"^4.13.1",
    "normalizr":"^3.6.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin":"5.0.3",
    "pluralize":"^8.0.0",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin":"1.6.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes":"4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader":"3.0.0",
    "postcss-normalize":"8.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env":"6.7.0",
    "postcss-safe-parser":"4.0.1",
    "query-string":"^6.12.0",
    "quill-mention":"^3.1.0",
    "rc-tree-select":"^4.1.2",
    "react":"^16.13.0",
    "react-add-to-homescreen":"^1.1.0",
    "react-app-polyfill":"^1.0.6",
    "react-cookie":"^4.0.3",
    "react-dev-utils":"^10.2.0",
    "react-device-detect":"^1.14.0",
    "react-dnd":"^10.0.2",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend":"^10.0.2",
    "react-dom":"^16.13.0",
    "react-helmet":"^6.1.0",
    "react-hook-inview":"^4.3.8",
    "react-html-parser":"^2.0.2",
    "react-lines-ellipsis":"^0.14.1",
    "react-markdown":"^5.0.3",
    "react-material-ui-carousel":"^3.4.2",
    "react-mixpanel":"^1.0.5",
    "react-mixpanel-browser":"^3.1.4",
    "react-quill":"2.0.0-beta.2",
    "react-redux":"^7.2.0",
    "react-router":"^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom":"^5.1.2",
    "react-sortable-hoc":"^2.0.0",
    "react-sticky":"^6.0.3",
    "react-textarea-autosize":"^8.3.4",
    "react-timeago":"^4.4.0",
    "recharts":"^1.8.5",
    "redux-persist":"^6.0.0",
    "resolve":"1.15.0",
    "resolve-url-loader":"3.1.1",
    "sass-loader":"^7.3.1",
    "semver":"6.3.0",
    "smoothscroll-polyfill":"^0.4.4",
    "style-loader":"^1.1.3",
    "styled-components":"^5.3.6",
    "terser-webpack-plugin":"2.3.4",
    "timeago-react":"^3.0.0",
    "ts-pnp":"1.1.5",
    "ttl-counter":"^1.0.3",
    "typescript":"~4.7.3",
    "url-loader":"2.3.0",
    "use-query-params":"^1.1.9",
    "webpack":"4.41.5",
    "webpack-dev-server":"3.10.2",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin":"2.2.0",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin":"4.3.1"
  },
  "scripts":{
    "start":"node scripts/start.js",
    "serve":"serve -s -p 5000 build",
    "build":"node --max-old-space-size=8192 scripts/build.js",
    "build:serve":"yarn build && serve -s build",
    "test":"node scripts/test.js --watchAll=false",
    "test:watch":"yarn test --watchAll",
    "test:coverage":"yarn test --coverage --watchAll=false",
    "storybook":"start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook":"build-storybook",
    "cy:open":"NODE_ENV=production cypress open",
    "cy:run":"NODE_ENV=production cypress run --record --key c41c26c5-1911-4c4c-982b-a298d215ae61",
    "cy:build:open":"NODE_ENV=production start-server-and-test build:serve http://localhost:5000 cy:open",
    "cy:build:run":"NODE_ENV=production start-server-and-test build:serve http://localhost:5000 cy:run",
    "lint":"eslint './src/**' --quiet",
    "lint-fix":"eslint './src/**' --fix"
  },
  "eslintConfig":{
    "extends":"react-app"
  },
  "browserslist":{
    "production":[
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "staging":[
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development":[
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "babel":{
    "presets":[
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies":{
    "@babel/helper-define-map":"^7.13.12",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties":"^7.13.0",
    "@nodeworks/antd-scss-theme-plugin":"^2.0.3",
    "@storybook/addon-actions":"^6.5.15",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials":"^6.5.15",
    "@storybook/addon-links":"^6.5.15",
    "@storybook/react":"^6.5.15",
    "@testing-library/cypress":"^8.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin":"^5.29.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser":"^5.29.0",
    "antd-scss-theme-plugin":"^1.0.8",
    "cypress-dotenv":"^2.0.0",
    "eslint":"^7.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress":"^2.12.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react":"^7.21.5",
    "jsdom":"^17.0.0",
    "less-loader":"^5.0.0",
    "serve":"^12.0.0",
    "start-server-and-test":"^1.12.5",
    "storybook-readme":"^5.0.9",
    "ts-jest":"^27.0.5",
    "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin":"^3.3.0"
  }
}
```

I'm not really sure why it would throw that error if the browserlist is already there.

I was following the docs to add more memory to my step for node https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/step-options/#Size.

I wonder if it doesn't have enough memory to process that?

Here is the bitbucket-pipelines.yml config file

```
image: node:14

definitions:

steps:

 - step: &test

name: Test

script:

 - yarn

 - yarn test --detectOpenHandles --forceExit --changedSince $BITBUCKET_BRANCH

 - step: &build

name: Build

size: 2x

script:

 - yarn

 - NODE_ENV=${BUILD_ENV} yarn build

artifacts:

 - build/**

 - step: &deploy_s3

name: Deploy to S3

script:

 - pipe: atlassian/aws-s3-deploy:0.3.8

variables:

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION

S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET

LOCAL_PATH: "./build/"

ACL: 'public-read'

 - step: &auto_merge_down

name: Auto Merge Down

script:

 - ./autoMerge.sh stage || true

 - ./autoMerge.sh dev || true

caches:

jest: /tmp/jest_*

node-dev: ./node_modules

node-stage: ./node_modules

node-release: ./node_modules

node-prod: ./node_modules

pipelines:

branches:

feature/optimize-build-sourcemaps-and-memory:

 - parallel:

fail-fast: true

steps:

# - step:

# caches:

# - node-release

# - jest

# <<: *test

 - step:

caches:

 - node-release

<<: *build

deployment: Release Env

dev:

 - parallel:

fail-fast: true

steps:

 - step:

caches:

 - node-dev

 - jest

<<: *test

 - step:

caches:

 - node-dev

<<: *build

deployment: Dev Env

 - step:

<<: *deploy_s3

deployment: Dev

stage:

 - parallel:

fail-fast: true

steps:

 - step:

caches:

 - node-stage

 - jest

<<: *test

 - step:

caches:

 - node-stage

<<: *build

deployment: Staging Env

 - step:

<<: *deploy_s3

deployment: Staging

prod:

 - parallel:

fail-fast: true

steps:

 - step:

caches:

 - node-prod

 - jest

<<: *test

 - step:

caches:

 - node-prod

<<: *build

deployment: Production Env

 - parallel:

steps:

 - step:

<<: *deploy_s3

deployment: Production

 - step:

<<: *auto_merge_down
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the definition of the browserlist in package.json from

```
"browserslist": {
  "production": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "development": [
    "last 1 chrome version",
    "last 1 firefox version",
    "last 1 safari version"
  ]
},
```

to

```
"browserslist": [
  ">0.2%",
  "not dead",
  "not op_mini all"
],
```

worked for me.